# Site moved between servers, url now has /default in them

Tags: url-rewrite, product-urls

The magento site been moved with all files from Server A to Server B, everything working fine until we noticed a small change with the URLs.

Before the move the url would be domain.com/category-a

After the move the url is now domain.com/default/category-a

Checking the URL rewrites, Base URL and the nginx conf file I see now sign of were the default is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the system configuration at *General > Web > Url Options* and set "Add Store Code to Urls" to "No":

[image: screenshot]